# JVM 8 SIGSEGV: which could be the cause?

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, segmentation-fault, jvm

I received this error after more than 2 years of continous running without any problem:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc4ec043340, pid=1143, tid=0x00007fc4bcb85700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0.102-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007fc4ec043340
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/fportal/jaxx/leo/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/core or core.1143
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/fportal/jaxx/leo/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/hs_err_pid1143.log
Compiled method (c1) -1570440943 731555909   !   1      java.text.SimpleDateFormat::subParse (1765 bytes)
```

Any thoughts on which could be the cause?

Comment: You could be a victim of a [Soft error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error), i.e. something caused not by your program, but by a defect in your memory, be it your harware or even cosmic rays (Yes that can happen)

Comment: I don't know the cause of the SIGSEGV, but now would be a good time to update your environment, since both [Java 1.8u102](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-19116/version_id-203278/Oracle-JDK-1.8.0.html) as well as [Apache Tomcat 7.0.42](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-887/version_id-160343/Apache-Tomcat-7.0.42.html) have well known security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Related: [How to know the reason for JVM crashing with Segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835460/how-to-know-the-reason-for-jvm-crashing-with-segfault), [Best way on how to solve/debug JVM crash (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109313/best-way-on-how-to-solve-debug-jvm-crash-sigsegv)

Comment: Thanks to all! I encountered this problem only one time. It could be, of course, a rare soft error event. As a first step, I will ask sysadmins if they updated the underlying OS. I know that is also a good thing to update JVM and Tomcat to new versions (this can be the next action), but at the moment I'll keep waiting if the error happens again.

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump):

> computer program at a specific time, generally when the program has crashed or otherwise terminated abnormally

For your question: `What is the root cause ?`, the main issue when `2 years of continous running` is a patch that has upgraded a library or the kernel (operating system), that your software, being older, doesn't know about.

So, you will have to upgrade your system with the latest, probably upgrading [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and or JRE (Java).

Comment: Thank you. Upgrading JVM and Tomcat is not an easy task, due to host organization constraints. Since the error occurred only one time, I'll keep monitoring the application, hoping the error will not occur again. If not so, I'll preprare to upgrade JVM and Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The specific issue that you've hit here is a segmentation fault when running a Java method which has been compiled; in this case, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat::subParse`. It's probably an error caused by a compilation of that code to native code and there being an error in that generation.

Given that the date parsing can be complex (e.g. TimeZone IDs, positive/negative offsets) it's likely it was triggered by a date format being passed in with dodgy value that would otherwise cause a NullPointerException in Java but was already compiled at a C2 level and some compilation/inlining failure has resulted in an unhandled SIGSEV.

If you find out how to reproduce it then you can raise a bug with the logs that might give a clue, but being able to reproduce it might not be practical.

Lastly, as others have noted, upgrading the JVM will get you further benefits and other fixes, so it's something worth considering.

Comment: Yes, I'm not able to reproduce the error, i.e. I don't know which were the actual parameters for that specific invocation of the SimpleDateFormat methods. And I agree, JVM upgrade can be the best (or only...) remediaion action to take.